# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

Hi I am a newbie to Objective C and I don't have a mac I'm using online compiler available at compileonline.com. Today I wrote the following program

```
 1 #import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
 2 int main(){
 3   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
 4   NSString * firstName = @"Eric";
 5   NSString * lastName  = @"Simmons";
 6   NSString * fullName = [[firstName stringByAppendingString: @" "]stringByAppendingString: lastName];
 7   NSLog(fullName);//prints Eric Simmons
 8   NSLog (@"The Entered full name is :",fullName);// Just prints The entered full name is : 
 9   NSString * correctFullName = [fullName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: firstName withString: @"Derrick"];
 10  NSLog(correctFullName);//prints Derrick Simmons
 11   NSLog(@"The correct full name : ",correctFullName);// Just prints The correct full name is : 
 12  [pool drain];
 13   return 0;
 14 }
```

However this program works well. But output is not what I expected . Output looks like this

```
Executing the program....
2014-01-02 05:42:27.958 demo[18115] Eric Simmons
2014-01-02 05:42:27.959 demo[18115] The Entered full name is :
2014-01-02 05:42:27.959 demo[18115] Derrick Simmons
2014-01-02 05:42:27.959 demo[18115] The correct full name :
```

The names are not getting printed when the line 8 and 11 are executed. Where I have gone wrong. Is it a error in program or is it bug in compiler. Please help...

Comment: you just forgot to add the %@ in the NSLog.

Comment: @Suresh tnx alot !! Its my first day with objective C.

Comment: @iamyogish Welcome to Objective-C and Stackoverflow you will love both :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 8 & 11
You forgot the format specifier

```
NSLog (@"The Entered full name is : %@",fullName);
NSLog(@"The correct full name : %@",correctFullName);
```

Comment: Would you like to suggest any online tutorials for objective C for me??

Comment: Ofcourse man i always help the newbies. Just visit this tutorial website. http://www.raywenderlich.com/ awesome website. This site is always on my browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need format specifier to print the string.

Use **%@** to print strings like below:

```
 NSLog (@"The Entered full name is : %@",fullName);
```

Comment: Thank you.. Its a first day of mine :) thanks alot :)